# get the data and the masked values as 0?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have a masked array.
I can get back the data via array.data, but this does not filter the data trough the mask.

How can I can get the data, but in the place where there is mask to get zero.

---

Here is what I got so far :

```
 ary.data * (~ary.mask).astype(byte)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `numpy.ma.filled()`:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.ma.masked_greater(np.random.rand(10), 0.5)
print np.ma.filled(m, 0)
```